# PLSQL Declare asks for INTO in second Select block

Tags: plsql

I keep in getting the following errors:

> ORA-06550: line 17, column 1: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in
> this SELECT statement

But I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

```
ALTER SESSION  SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'ddmmyyyy';
DECLARE
  auditnr NUMBER := 200959;
  maxeinddatum DATE;
  auditdatum DATE;
  operatorid NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(aa.datum_eind_max), max(ao.datum_audit), max(ao.operator_id)
    INTO maxeinddatum, auditdatum, operatorid
    FROM autocontrole2.activiteit_audit aa,
         autocontrole2.audit_oci ao
    WHERE aa.audit_oci_id = auditnr and aa.audit_oci_id=ao.audit_oci_id;

  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(maxeinddatum || ',' || auditdatum || ',' || operatorid);



SELECT *
 FROM autocontrole2.pap_operator pap 
 WHERE pap.operator_id = operatorid
 AND pap.datum_begin <= auditdatum AND pap.datum_eind >= auditdatum;


END;
```

I've looked into CURSOR FOR, but I can't imagine that PLSQL isn't that straightforward, that I can't put 2 SELECT blocks together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty straightforward. Check what is on line 17 or just after

```
17 
18 SELECT *
19  FROM autocontrole2.pap_operator pap 
20  WHERE pap.operator_id = operatorid
21  AND pap.datum_begin <= auditdatum AND pap.datum_eind >= auditdatum;
```

That is just a select with no `INTO` clause. That is not possible in pl/sql - what should be done with the resultset of the select ? It should be something like:

```
SELECT *
 INTO <some variable to hold the results>
 FROM autocontrole2.pap_operator pap 
 WHERE pap.operator_id = operatorid
  AND pap.datum_begin <= auditdatum AND pap.datum_eind >= auditdatum;
```

Let's have a look at an example on the sample EMP table. This is similar to your code:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM EMP WHERE ename = 'KING';
END;
/

Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
BEGIN
  SELECT *  FROM EMP WHERE ename = 'KING';
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 3, column 3:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

The fix is to select INTO a variable:

```
DECLARE
  l_emp EMP%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO l_emp FROM EMP WHERE ename = 'KING';
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```